# Adding alert to canvas faces

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm currently trying to make so that when you click on one of the happy face you get an alert box which says "thanks for the feed back", but I'm currently not sure to to incoperate that in tho my code! Thanks! Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bsjs9/

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>SmileMore</title>

    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>
                        Bring your Charts to life with HTML5 Canvas</h1>
                </hgroup>
                <p>
                    Rendering Dynamic charts in JS
                </p>
                <div class="smile">
    <canvas id="myDrawing" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #EEE"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #EEE"></canvas>   
         </div>

                <script>
                  var FacePainter = function(canvasName)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasName);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var x = canvas.width / 2;
    var y = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 75;
    var startAngle = 0;
    var endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;

    function drawFace() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.fill();
    }

    function drawSmile(startAngle, endAngle)
    {
        var x = canvas.width / 2;
        var y = 150;
        var radius = 40;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle * Math.PI, endAngle * Math.PI);
        ctx.lineWidth = 7;

        // line color
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function drawEyes() {
        var centerX = 40;
        var centerY = 0;
        var radius = 10;

        // save state
        ctx.save();

        // translate context so height is 1/3'rd from top of enclosing circle
        ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 3);

        // scale context horizontally by 50%
        ctx.scale(.5, 1);

        // draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

        // restore to original state
        ctx.restore();

        // apply styling
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.stroke();

        //left eye
        var centerX = -40;
        var centerY = 0;
        var radius = 10;

        // save state
        ctx.save();

        // translate context so height is 1/3'rd from top of enclosing circle
        ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 3);

        // scale context horizontally by 50%
        ctx.scale(.5, 1);

        // draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

        // restore to original state
        ctx.restore();

        // apply styling
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    this.drawHappyFace = function() {
        drawFace();
        drawEyes();
        drawSmile(1.1, 1.9);
    }

    this.drawSadFace = function() {
        drawFace();
        drawEyes();
        drawSmile(1.9, 1.1);

        ;
    }
}

new FacePainter('canvas').drawHappyFace();
new FacePainter('myDrawing').drawSadFace();



                </script>    

</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

As an extra assignment I would like to know if anyone knows how to fix the "happy" smile, its kinda way off! Thanks all!

Comment: If your faces are going to be in set positions on the page, you could add a click event to the whole page and use the cursor position to decide which one they have clicked on.  Then alert whatever based on that.

Comment: +1 @Seano666. To fix the smile, you have to draw that circle higher on the happy face. Both mouths are drawn from a circle whose center is at the same height, which is bad. Check out the update [-Here-](http://jsfiddle.net/bsjs9/1/). By the way, I think your drawHappyFace function draws the sad face and drawSadFace draws the happy face... fyi

Comment: Thanks a lot both for the answers, Tyrannical thanks for fixing the smile problem! Sean however, I was to center the pictures eventually but what you described sounds perfect, but I dont really know how to execute it. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you draw the happy face on its own canvas, you can simple put an `onclick` handler on the canvas.

```
<canvas id="myDrawing" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #EEE" onclick="alert('thanks');"></canvas>
```

Regarding the smiles, I added a new `ofsy` parameter to `drawSmile`, which offsets the arc origin vertically.

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6S9zD/).

If you only want to show the alert, when the user clicks *inside* the face, you need to get the click coordinates and hittest it against the circle. You can see this in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6S9zD/1/).